# Measurable functions on an uncountable set

Tags: real-analysis

If X is an uncountable set and A is sigma algebra on X that is generated by all singletons in X and f is a function from X to real numbers and the sigma algebra on real numbers is  set of the Borel sets.then f is a measurable function if an only if....?

Comment: Do you know the definition of measurable function?  Do you have a grasp of which subsets of $X$ are measurable sets?

Comment: Yes I am studying real analysis and I just learned measurable functions

Comment: Yes exactly Borel sets

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\mathcal{A}:=\left\{ B\in\wp\left(X\right)\mid B\text{ is countable}\vee X-B\text{ is countable}\right\} $
is a $\sigma$-algebra.

---

**addendum**:

> function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is a measurable function if and only if its image is countable and exactly one of its fibres is uncountable.

Fibres of $f$ are preimages of singletons, i.e. sets of the form $\left\{ x\in X\mid f\left(x\right)=r\right\} $ where $r\in\mathbb{R}$. My hint was meant as an indication the $\mathcal A$ is here the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ generated by the singletons in $X$.

**Proof**:

Suppose that the image of $f$, i.e. the set $f\left(X\right):=\left\{ f\left(x\right)\mid x\in X\right\} \subseteq\mathbb{R}$
is uncountable. Then a Borelset $B\subset\mathbb{R}$ can be found
such that $f\left(X\right)\cap B$ and $f\left(X\right)\backslash B$
are both uncountable. For a proof of that look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/884894/75923). Consequently
the preimages under $f$ of the sets $B$ and its complement $B^{c}=\mathbb{R}\backslash B$
are both uncountable hence do not belong to $\mathcal{A}$. Proved
is now that $f$ can only be measurable if its image is countable.
If its image is indeed countable then $f$ must have fibres that are
uncountable. This because the union of these fibres form the uncountable set $X$. If $r,s\in\mathbb{R}$ are distinct then fibres $f^{-1}\left(r\right)$
and $f^{-1}\left(s\right)$ are disjoint so if they are both uncountable then none of them
can belong to $\mathcal{A}$. Proved is now that $f$ can only be
measurable if exactly one of its fibres is uncountable.

If conversely both conditions
are satisfied then
indeed $f$ is measurable. If $f^{-1}\left(r\right)$ is its unique uncountable fibre then $X\backslash f^{-1}\left(r\right)=\bigcup_{s\in f\left(X\right)\backslash\left\{ r\right\} }f^{-1}\left(s\right)$
is a countable union of countable sets, hence is countable itself. For any preimage $f^{-1}\left(U\right)$ we have $f^{-1}\left(U\right)\subset X\backslash f^{-1}\left(r\right)$
or $X\backslash f^{-1}\left(U\right)\subset X\backslash f^{-1}\left(r\right)$
and in both cases $f^{-1}\left(U\right)\in\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Heh, I only realized what your Comment was getting at when I saw this!

Comment: After a second look I realized that this is not such an easy question. I hope edit helps.